# Hidden Markov Model with Continuously Timed Events

Tags: hidden-markov-model

In an HMM we have a sequence of observations where only the order of observations is preserved $(t=1, t=2, \dots)$, but exact timing is unimportant.

Is there a way to model sequence of observations where to each observation a continuous time stamp is attached $(t=1, t=2.5, \dots)$?

Comment: What is the context?  What is your hidden state?  Do you think of your hidden state as changing in discrete time (e.g. there is a possible transition every 0.5 units of time), or continuously?

Comment: @Adrian Consider, as an example, a video in which certain events may occur, such as walking, running, stopping, and so on. One needs to model this random process using HMM (or even a better tool, if any). Normally you would define your alphabet as the set of possible actions and the sequence of observed action would constitute your observation. However in this case exact timing matters in addition to order. I don't impose any restrictions on the hidden states. Anything that can solve this would be OK.

Comment: What exactly are your data? Are you observing the process at discrete time points or continuously? - and do you know the transition time points or are you trying to infer them?

Comment: I think you are looking for non-stationary HMMs which have been designed to model state duration that classic HMMs are not able to capture.

Comment: However it is hard to say if they would answer your problem without more details about your data and your goal.

Comment: @S.Catterall Yes, it is possible to see the time of observations.